# Adding elements to some sublists of unequal length

Tags: list-manipulation, symbolic

Complicated title for a simple problem:
I have list

```
a = {{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2}}
```

In which the first element of each sublist is basically an index. The following values are the actual data.
Then I want to add data to this list, e.g.,:

```
b = {{2, 1}, {4, 3}}
```

Which means that to the list with the index '2' the '1' should be added and the list with the index '4' the '3' should be added, so the result reads:

```
{{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}
```

I found a couple of rather complicated, i.e., time consuming solutions involving loops. However, the actual datset is huge and is part of a numerical simulation, i.e., this procedure needs to be very fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Fold[Insert[#1, Last[#2], {First[#2], -1}] &, a, b]
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this:

```
ReplacePart[a, #1 -> Append[a[[#1]], #2]& @@@ b]
```

If data are large and speedup is needed you might want to try `Join`

```
ReplacePart[a, #1 -> Join[a[[#1]], {#2}] & @@@ b]
```

In case you want value of `a` to be the new list with added elements, you whether can use `AppendTo`:

```
ReplacePart[a, #1 -> AppendTo[a[[#1]], #2] & @@@ b]
```

or simply reassign:

```
a = ReplacePart[a, #1 -> Append[a[[#1]], #2] & @@@ b]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make `b` into a list of rules

```
rules = {#, a__} :> {#, a, #2} & @@@ b;
```

and use it with `ReplaceAll`:

```
a /. rules
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}

or with `Replace`:

```
Replace[a, rules, All]
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}

This approach works for any ordering of the elements in the input list:

```
c = RandomSample[a]
```

> {{2, 6, 2}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 5, 2}, {4, 2}}

```
c /. rules
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}

```
Replace[c, rules, All]
```

> {{2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {1, 3, 5, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

From the `Association` universe:

```
KeyValueMap[Flatten @* List] @ Merge[# &] @ Map[GroupBy[First -> Rest], {a, b}]
```

{{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}

Or

```
KeyValueMap[Flatten @* List] @ Merge[# &] @ MapApply[#1 -> {##2} &, Join[a, b]]
```

{{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2}};
b = {{2, 1}, {4, 3}};

c = Join[b, Array[{#, x} &, Length@a]] // DeleteDuplicatesBy[First] //
   SortBy[First]
```

> {{1, x}, {2, 1}, {3, x}, {4, 3}}

**Using `Join`:**

Join the second column of `c` with `a` and delete the `x`:

```
Join[a, List /@ c[[All, 2]], 2] /. x -> Nothing
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

Another method using `GroupBy`:

```
Values[GroupBy[Catenate[{a, b}], First, If[Length[#] == 2, 
Sequence @@@ {#[[1, All]], #[[2]][[2;;]]}, #[[1]]] &]]

(*{{1, 3, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 1}, {3, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}}*)
```